# Change webpage URL and preserve it based on $_POST value

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post

I have a WordPress website with `header.php` called for every single page. On `header.php`, I have a form on which the user can select a product category. On change, the form will redirect the user to my category page, which is `category.php` on my server but appears as /category when browsing the site.

**On header.php**:

```
<form method="POST" action="category" id="cateogry-filter-pick">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="category-filter" name="cat">
        <?php 
        $category_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT product_category FROM $table_name;");
        foreach($category_list as $key => $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $row->product_category);?>"><?php echo $row->product_category;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

**on Custom-js.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#category-filter').on('change', function() {
        this.form.submit();
    }); 
});
```

**On category.php**, I can asign the category to a variable, and then loop to display all my results, using:

```
$product_category = isset($_POST['cat']) ? $_POST['cat'] : null;
```

On my category page, I am also using some sorting filters with AJAX / $_GET, which would change the URL to something like this:

```
/category/?sort=rating
```

When doing so, I lose the value of the category sent from any previous `$_POST`.

What I would ultimately want to do is to change my page URL from `/category` to `/the-name-of-the-category/` (which is `$_POST['cat']`) and preserve this value when I use my sort filters. My URL would then become something like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/shoes/?sort=rating
```

What is the best approach to do so, considering that I also want users who type a URL in their browser such as `www.mywebsite.com/shoes` to access the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry for bad english)

When you submit a form (submit button or javascript), it will redirect to form's action (`action="category"`) to:

```
url: www.mywebsite.com/category
```

if you want to be redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/your-category` you must do that in **category.php**:

```
$product_category = isset($_POST['cat']) ? $_POST['cat'] : null;

if($product_category)
{
    $url = "www.mywebsite.com/".$product_category;
}
```

and if you want to preserve `?sort=rating` or another `$_GET` vars without lost your previous category, you must append to your url in **category.php**:

```
$url = "www.mywebsite.com/".$product_category."/?".$my_get_vars;
```

in which `$my_get_vars` contains the query part of your previous url

But if your filters (query vars) come from an ajax call, you must send your ajax request to current url: `www.mywebsite.com/selected-category` not to `www.mywebsite.com/category.php` to preserve your selected category.

---

Hope this help!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what would be within the `if ` condition. Can the redirect be automatic?

Comment: sorry, answer send before i coud finish it, now it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just not too sure what I should do with the `$url`

Comment: $url is an example, what i want to say is you must make your filters (ajax calls) to `www.mywebsite.com/yout-selected-category` to preserve the category you had selected.